# How to create global variable in nested function using tkinter?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, global, nested-function

I wrote some code using tkinter and some nested functions (see code below) and get the warning in pycharm "Global variable 'value' is undefined at the module level". The program works as intended (the window title is renamed to 'text 0') but i still get the warning... What do i have to change to get rid of this warning? (the program is more complex, i need to start it like it does, with `window.after` and i also need all the functions)

```
from tkinter import *

def function_1():
   global value
   window.title("text " + value)

def function_2():
   def function_3():
       global value
       value = ent.get()
       if value == '0':
          function_1()
   ent = Entry()
   ent.pack()
   button = Button(text="ok", command=function_3)
   button.pack()


window = Tk()
window.after(0, function_2)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `button = Button(text="ok", command=function_3)` doesn't work because "function_3" is not a module level variable.

Comment: Did you intend to return `function_3` from `function_2` and do `button = Button(text="ok", command=function_2())`?

Comment: sorry the code was not indented, it is in function 2

Comment: Right, but the problem is that `function_3` is not visible to `command=function3`. Running the code gets `NameError: name 'function_3' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `global` keyword is used inside a function to control assignment to a variable. Normally within a function `value = "bar"` creates a "value" in the local function namespace. `global value` in that same function tells python to use the global namespace instead.

In your current code, the module level `value` variable will not come into existence until `function_3` is called. Anything that tries to use `value` before `function_3` is called will get a `NameError`. `function_1` is a case in point; if it is called before `function_3`, you have an error. It may be that your code can never call `function_1` before `function_3` but that is difficult for a linter or future maintiainers of the code to know. That's why you get the warning.

The solution is to set a default for value that is sensible for the program. I don't know what works for you, but here is an example that throws up a message. BTW, `global value` is not needed in `function_1`. Its job is to control assignment, you can read global variables without any additional annotation.

```
from tkinter import *

value = None

def function_1():
   if value is not None:
       window.title("text " + value)
   else:
       import tkinter.messagebox
       tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Do the thing before the thing")

def function_2():
   def function_3():
       global value
       value = ent.get()
       if value == '0':
          function_1()

   ent = Entry()
   ent.pack()
   button = Button(text="ok", command=function_3)
   button.pack()
  
window = Tk()
window.after(0, function_2)
window.mainloop()
```